# Android how to get components inside a layout to take up an equal percentage of space

Tags: android, layout

For examples two buttons inside a linear layout or a relative layout.  Have each button always take up 50% of space in parent container. How is this specified? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout>
<Button
    layout_weight="0.5"
/>
<Button
    layout_weight="0.5"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

each button will take 50% of the linearLayout.